# What is this icon on top right of screen?

Tags: panel, top-bar

How can I identify what the icons on the top bar (right hand side) are?

[image: panel in top right corner]

I'm specifically interested in the leftmost icon.

Comment: I have found out what that icon is for. It is to toggle touch screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is to "Toggle the touchscreen" shortcut for the setting found in the gnome-tweak-tool